# Regex expression to validate ONLY hindi (devnagri) letters in PYTHON

Tags: python, regex, tokenize, normalize, hindi

I am trying to build a tokenizer which takes in Hindi sentence and removes any other scripts present in it.

This is my code that i have written and the output is attached as well.

I tried this

```
import re
s = "विश्व कप sdsd 12वें संस्करण जनवरी12 or 12जनवरी or जनवरी22"
combining_marks = '[\u0300-\u036F\u0483-\u0489\u0591-\u05BD\u05BF\u05C1\u05C2\u05C4\u05C5\u05C7\u0610-\u061A\u064B-\u065F\u0670\u06D6-\u06DC\u06DF-\u06E4\u06E7\u06E8\u06EA-\u06ED\u0711\u0730-\u074A\u07A6-\u07B0\u07EB-\u07F3\u07FD\u0816-\u0819\u081B-\u0823\u0825-\u0827\u0829-\u082D\u0859-\u085B\u08D3-\u08E1\u08E3-\u0903\u093A-\u093C\u093E-\u094F\u0951-\u0957\u0962\u0963\u0981-\u0983\u09BC\u09BE-\u09C4\u09C7\u09C8\u09CB-\u09CD\u09D7\u09E2\u09E3\u09FE\u0A01-\u0A03\u0A3C\u0A3E-\u0A42\u0A47\u0A48\u0A4B-\u0A4D\u0A51\u0A70\u0A71\u0A75\u0A81-\u0A83\u0ABC\u0ABE-\u0AC5\u0AC7-\u0AC9\u0ACB-\u0ACD\u0AE2\u0AE3\u0AFA-\u0AFF\u0B01-\u0B03\u0B3C\u0B3E-\u0B44\u0B47\u0B48\u0B4B-\u0B4D\u0B56\u0B57\u0B62\u0B63\u0B82\u0BBE-\u0BC2\u0BC6-\u0BC8\u0BCA-\u0BCD\u0BD7\u0C00-\u0C04\u0C3E-\u0C44\u0C46-\u0C48\u0C4A-\u0C4D\u0C55\u0C56\u0C62\u0C63\u0C81-\u0C83\u0CBC\u0CBE-\u0CC4\u0CC6-\u0CC8\u0CCA-\u0CCD\u0CD5\u0CD6\u0CE2\u0CE3\u0D00-\u0D03\u0D3B\u0D3C\u0D3E-\u0D44\u0D46-\u0D48\u0D4A-\u0D4D\u0D57\u0D62\u0D63\u0D82\u0D83\u0DCA\u0DCF-\u0DD4\u0DD6\u0DD8-\u0DDF\u0DF2\u0DF3\u0E31\u0E34-\u0E3A\u0E47-\u0E4E\u0EB1\u0EB4-\u0EBC\u0EC8-\u0ECD\u0F18\u0F19\u0F35\u0F37\u0F39\u0F3E\u0F3F\u0F71-\u0F84\u0F86\u0F87\u0F8D-\u0F97\u0F99-\u0FBC\u0FC6\u102B-\u103E\u1056-\u1059\u105E-\u1060\u1062-\u1064\u1067-\u106D\u1071-\u1074\u1082-\u108D\u108F\u109A-\u109D\u135D-\u135F\u1712-\u1714\u1732-\u1734\u1752\u1753\u1772\u1773\u17B4-\u17D3\u17DD\u180B-\u180D\u1885\u1886\u18A9\u1920-\u192B\u1930-\u193B\u1A17-\u1A1B\u1A55-\u1A5E\u1A60-\u1A7C\u1A7F\u1AB0-\u1ABE\u1B00-\u1B04\u1B34-\u1B44\u1B6B-\u1B73\u1B80-\u1B82\u1BA1-\u1BAD\u1BE6-\u1BF3\u1C24-\u1C37\u1CD0-\u1CD2\u1CD4-\u1CE8\u1CED\u1CF4\u1CF7-\u1CF9\u1DC0-\u1DF9\u1DFB-\u1DFF\u20D0-\u20F0\u2CEF-\u2CF1\u2D7F\u2DE0-\u2DFF\u302A-\u302F\u3099\u309A\uA66F-\uA672\uA674-\uA67D\uA69E\uA69F\uA6F0\uA6F1\uA802\uA806\uA80B\uA823-\uA827\uA880\uA881\uA8B4-\uA8C5\uA8E0-\uA8F1\uA8FF\uA926-\uA92D\uA947-\uA953\uA980-\uA983\uA9B3-\uA9C0\uA9E5\uAA29-\uAA36\uAA43\uAA4C\uAA4D\uAA7B-\uAA7D\uAAB0\uAAB2-\uAAB4\uAAB7\uAAB8\uAABE\uAABF\uAAC1\uAAEB-\uAAEF\uAAF5\uAAF6\uABE3-\uABEA\uABEC\uABED\uFB1E\uFE00-\uFE0F\uFE20-\uFE2F\U000101FD\U000102E0\U00010376-\U0001037A\U00010A01-\U00010A03\U00010A05\U00010A06\U00010A0C-\U00010A0F\U00010A38-\U00010A3A\U00010A3F\U00010AE5\U00010AE6\U00010D24-\U00010D27\U00010F46-\U00010F50\U00011000-\U00011002\U00011038-\U00011046\U0001107F-\U00011082\U000110B0-\U000110BA\U00011100-\U00011102\U00011127-\U00011134\U00011145\U00011146\U00011173\U00011180-\U00011182\U000111B3-\U000111C0\U000111C9-\U000111CC\U0001122C-\U00011237\U0001123E\U000112DF-\U000112EA\U00011300-\U00011303\U0001133B\U0001133C\U0001133E-\U00011344\U00011347\U00011348\U0001134B-\U0001134D\U00011357\U00011362\U00011363\U00011366-\U0001136C\U00011370-\U00011374\U00011435-\U00011446\U0001145E\U000114B0-\U000114C3\U000115AF-\U000115B5\U000115B8-\U000115C0\U000115DC\U000115DD\U00011630-\U00011640\U000116AB-\U000116B7\U0001171D-\U0001172B\U0001182C-\U0001183A\U000119D1-\U000119D7\U000119DA-\U000119E0\U000119E4\U00011A01-\U00011A0A\U00011A33-\U00011A39\U00011A3B-\U00011A3E\U00011A47\U00011A51-\U00011A5B\U00011A8A-\U00011A99\U00011C2F-\U00011C36\U00011C38-\U00011C3F\U00011C92-\U00011CA7\U00011CA9-\U00011CB6\U00011D31-\U00011D36\U00011D3A\U00011D3C\U00011D3D\U00011D3F-\U00011D45\U00011D47\U00011D8A-\U00011D8E\U00011D90\U00011D91\U00011D93-\U00011D97\U00011EF3-\U00011EF6\U00016AF0-\U00016AF4\U00016B30-\U00016B36\U00016F4F\U00016F51-\U00016F87\U00016F8F-\U00016F92\U0001BC9D\U0001BC9E\U0001D165-\U0001D169\U0001D16D-\U0001D172\U0001D17B-\U0001D182\U0001D185-\U0001D18B\U0001D1AA-\U0001D1AD\U0001D242-\U0001D244\U0001DA00-\U0001DA36\U0001DA3B-\U0001DA6C\U0001DA75\U0001DA84\U0001DA9B-\U0001DA9F\U0001DAA1-\U0001DAAF\U0001E000-\U0001E006\U0001E008-\U0001E018\U0001E01B-\U0001E021\U0001E023\U0001E024\U0001E026-\U0001E02A\U0001E130-\U0001E136\U0001E2EC-\U0001E2EF\U0001E8D0-\U0001E8D6\U0001E944-\U0001E94A\U000E0100-\U000E01EF]'
mo = re.compile(r"\w+|\S".format(combining_marks))
print(mo.findall(s))
```

---

**Output :-**

```
['व', 'ि', 'श', '्', 'व', 'कप', 'sdsd', '12व', 'े', 'ं', 'स', 'ं', 'स', '्', 'करण', 'जनवर', 'ी', '1', '2', 'or', '12', 'जनवर', 'ी', 'or', 'जनवर', 'ी', '22']
```

as you can see that it even prints *'sdsd' ,'or* which is english and it somehow prints the "Maatraye" in Hindi or 'ि   '्'  'ी'   'ं' separately, i want them to be together like they are in the input i have given to the model.

Comment: Your `.format` has no effect since the string before doesn't contain any `{}`. Use `{}+` instead

Comment: Right now your `combining_marks` isn't used at all. You are just using `\w+` which is word characters in any language

Comment: @Ikshan If you only want Devanagari characters, simplest approach would be to use the regex module: `import regex as re`. Then create a Unicode regex pattern: `pattern = r'\p{Deva}+'`. Then find all matches: `result = re.findall(pattern, s)`. That should give you `['विश्व', 'कप', 'वें', 'संस्करण', 'जनवरी', 'जनवरी', 'जनवरी']`

Comment: @mousetail `\w+` is NOT word characters in any language. The re module's implementation of `\w` does not match the Unicode definition of word forming characters. For Devanagari using `\w+` will not match a number of word forming characters. In the regex in question, some Devanagari characters are matched by `\w+` while others Devanagari letters matched by `\S`. That is the reason that Hindi words are broken up.

Answer (score 2):

Try this as a start:

```
standalone = r'[\u0904-\u0939\u0964-\u097F]'
modifiers = r'[\u0900-\u0903\u093A-\u094F]'
mo = re.compile(f'{standalone}{modifiers}*')
```

Which means, make sure there is one standalone character, and any number of following modifier characters. I only went through the Devanagari block, and hopefully got them all correctly; if you need extended blocks, you can see what I did and do the same thing, just add the corresponding ranges into standalone or composing, as appropriate.

---

EDIT:

Here's a better regexp for Devanagari letters with modifying marks:

```
[\u0904-\u0939\u093d-\u093d\u0950-\u0950\u0958-\u0961\u0964-\u097f\ua8f2-\ua8fe\U00011b00-\U00011b09\u1cd3-\u1cd3\u1ce9-\u1cec\u1cee-\u1cf3\u1cf5-\u1cf6\u1cfa-\u1cfa][\u0900-\u0903\u093a-\u093c\u093e-\u094f\u0951-\u0957\u0962-\u0963\ua8e0-\ua8f1\ua8ff-\ua8ff\u1cd0-\u1cd2\u1cd4-\u1ce8\u1ced-\u1ced\u1cf4-\u1cf4\u1cf7-\u1cf9]*
```

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/jFsuNs/1). I created it using this code:

```
import unicodedata
from itertools import groupby

blocks = [
    (0x0900, 0x097F),   # Devanagari
    (0xA8E0, 0xA8FF),   # Devanagari Extended
    (0x11B00, 0x11B09), # Devanagari Extended-A
    (0x1CD0, 0x1CFA),   # Vedic Extensions
]

chars = {
    False: [],
    True: [],
}

# Sort the characters into standalone ones and modifiers
for start, end in blocks:
    for o in range(start, end + 1):
        is_combining = unicodedata.category(chr(o))[0] == "M"
        chars[is_combining].append(o)

def format_char(o):
    # Format each character as a 16-bit or 32-bit Unicode literal
    return rf"\u{o:04x}" if o <= 0xFFFF else rf"\U{o:08x}"

# group each consecutive sublist and create a range    
ranges = {
    is_combining: ''.join(
        fr"{format_char(run[0][1])}-{format_char(run[-1][1])}"
        for run in [
            list(group)
            for _, group in groupby(enumerate(char_list), lambda p: p[0] - p[1])
        ]
    )
    for is_combining, char_list in chars.items()
}

# one standalone character followed by any number of modifier characters
pattern = f"[{ranges[False]}][{ranges[True]}]*"
print(pattern)
```

This answer understood the question as "each individual Devanagari letter". If you want to get words, enclode the given regexps in `(?:...)+`:

```
(?:[\u0904-\u0939\u093d-\u093d\u0950-\u0950\u0958-\u0961\u0964-\u097f\ua8f2-\ua8fe\U00011b00-\U00011b09\u1cd3-\u1cd3\u1ce9-\u1cec\u1cee-\u1cf3\u1cf5-\u1cf6\u1cfa-\u1cfa][\u0900-\u0903\u093a-\u093c\u093e-\u094f\u0951-\u0957\u0962-\u0963\ua8e0-\ua8f1\ua8ff-\ua8ff\u1cd0-\u1cd2\u1cd4-\u1ce8\u1ced-\u1ced\u1cf4-\u1cf4\u1cf7-\u1cf9]*)+
```

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/FhCSft/1)

Answer (score 0):

I see you are referring to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60111740/8353711). With a slight change to that(by removing `\d+`), you can get your desired output(only Hindi words) as shown below,

**Code:**

```
mo = re.compile(r'(?:(?![A-Za-z])[^\W\d_]{}*)+'.format(combining_marks))
print(mo.findall(s))
```

**Output:**

```
['विश्व', 'कप', 'वें', 'संस्करण', 'जनवरी', 'जनवरी', 'जनवरी']
```

Comment: It works for the particular input in the OP, but is not really general; for example, it will identify `é` as a Hindi letter (which it obviously is not).

Comment: @Amadan Those Unicode are obtained from [here](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=%5Cp%7BM%7D&abb=on&ucd=on&esc=on&g=&i=) which is to find all the marks which are same as provided by OP. For extracting only Devanagari letters, `re.findall(r'(?:(?![A-Za-z])[^\W\d_][\u0900-\u097F]*)+', s)` is enough.

Comment: `[^\W\d_][\u0900-\u097F]*` So you exclude some of the Devanagari letters by `[^\W\d_]` then you include the characters you excluded by using `[\u0900-\u097F]*` ?